# How can I prevent print error on website NuxtJS?

Tags: nuxt.js

By default, NuxtJS will print error on the website, I just want only error on Dev Tool/console. How can I custom the behaviour of Nuxt global error handler?

Answer (score 0):

- One important distinction you should know is  when you are running your application in `npm run dev` mode over a production `npm run build` mode, then you will see errors differently.

  **note**: the one with build won't show any error details.
- If you get an uncaught JavaScript error, then Nuxt will crash out of executing even if the exception occurs after you call error()
- If your error can be silently handled, like try and catch errors  while calling an API then you can.
  1-Use Nuxt Error page to display custom error.

  A- in your catch use this `error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Custom Error Goes Here' });`

    B- in layouts /errors.vue

  ```
     <template>
     <div class="container">
      <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">{{error.message}}</h1>
      <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
     </div>
      </template>
     <script>
     export default {
      name: "error",
      props: ['error'],
     }
    </script>
  ```

  2-Do nothing and the data are suppose to be displayed won't be displayed.

Comment: 1. I want to mention develop environment.

2. The error layout is just a solution for custom the error page. When an error occurred, it will be dispatch to Nuxt global error handle and Nuxt will create its own error, then redirect to the error page. I want to custom the behaviour of Nuxt global error handler.

So your answer is not the right answer.

Comment: I think you  cannot add your  own error handling because it's loaded before Nuxt's own middleware see here    https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/75350cdd78d17e565b6c58d6c1aaa00c5146cbae/lib/core/renderer.js#L277-L288, please correct me if i am wrong